# Prevent reading data from file for each pageview

Tags: c#, .net, variables

I run a C# .net site where I store four variables in "file.txt". Reason for storing in a .txt fil is the need of easy access to do changes.

The variables are used for every page the user get presented for the complete session. Reading the variables from the file for every pageview seems like unnecessary hard work.

Size of the .txt file is about 500 byte.

- I know the variables may be stored as session variables, but I've been reccomended not to have to mutch data stored in session.
- Another though was to cache the complete .txt file

What would be the best way to store those variables?

Comment: cache the variable for 30 minutes or whatever time you like

Comment: is the file changing frequently? are those changes required to be applied as soon as they are made?

Comment: @slawekwin , the file is not frequently changed. Maybe once each day. The changes does not have to be applied right away. Useres may complete their session with the old values, as long as new users get the new values.

Comment: 500 bytes is not that much data. How many users do you have? How often are the pages loaded?

Comment: @mortb Usually about 100 simulatious users and about 150 pageviews pr. minute. It peaks on about 500+ simultanious users.  That gives about 600 pagesviews pr. minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up caching the four strings instead of the file. Then I also prevent reading the filecontent for each pageload.

```
string cachedString;
cachedString = (string)Cache["CacheItem"];
if (cachedString == null)
{
  cachedString = "Hello, World.";
  Cache.Insert("CacheItem", cachedString);
}
```

Based on the code at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhy3h9f9.aspx) it turned out a rather basic solution. Just modified it to allow several strings. :)

Thanks for all inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use cache with expiration on file change

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;



public static TResult GetOrSetFileCache<TResult>(string key, Func<string, TResult> value, string path)
{
    if (MemoryCache.Default.Contains(key))
        return (TResult) MemoryCache.Default.Get(key);

    var val = value(key);

    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy
            {
                SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600)
            });
    policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new HostFileChangeMonitor(new List<string> { path }))

    MemoryCache.Default.Set(key, value, policy);

    return val;
}
```

HostFileChangeMonitor expires cache on file change and value() method executes to get new values.

Almost always it gets values from cache very fast.

Comment: Thanks for the code. This seems like the perfect answer to my question. Though while working with my project I found out there would be another way to solve this. Thanks anyway.